# Twig with ArrayAcess

Tags: php, twig, arrayaccess

I have a problem with dependency injection container and twig, I use `Illuminate/Container`:

```
// Register templates.
$this->singleton('templates', function ($c) {
    $twig = new \Twig_Environment(
        new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem([$c['paths.templates']]),
        [
            'debug' => true,
            // 'cache' => $c['paths.cache']
        ]
    );

    $twig->addExtension(new \Twig_Extension_Debug());

    $twig->addGlobal('app', $c['app']);

    return $twig;
});
```

`$c['app']` is the container.

And in my template file I wanna access to my bindings:

```
{{ app.config.siteName }}
```

But that didn't work for me, I think it's a problem because the container implements to ArrayAcess

Comment: Did you get an error message? What was it?

Comment: No. I tried this to know what is exactly the problem `{{ dump(app.config) }}` and it prints a null string. I also tried this `{{ dump(app.make('config') }}` and it works, but I wanna know why I can't access config like this `{{ app.config }}` ?!

Comment: Can you create a minimal example that shows your problem?